# Deleting acute accent in Angular2 using pipes

Tags: javascript, angular, formatting, pipes-filters

Is there any way to delete acute accent from the letters? I need lowercased and no special characters to get to the api.
For now I've applied lowercase pipe -> `{{f.value.cityForm | lowercase}}`
Example:

input: Abcdef -> abcdef (done)

input: ĄąbcćdęĘ -> aabccdee

input: ąĄĄććĆ -> aaaccc and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own pipe with [unidecode npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode).

```
@Pipe({name: 'unidecode'})
export class UnidecodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): number {
    return unidecode(value).toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: After `npm install unidecode` i get cannot find name unidecode in unicode.pipe.ts that I've created. Should I import it somewhere? I'm new to Angular2

Comment: It depends on your project configuration, but the following should work: first do `npm install @types/node --save-dev`, then import unidecode in your code with `const unidecode: any = require("unidecode")`